# Java, how to make a pause in JavaFX

Tags: java, button, javafx, sleep, pause

I have 4 buttons and I wanna make them blink. I need a pause for that purpose. How can I simply pause for like 500ms after each iteration? **Is it possible to do it without threads?**

```
public void blink() {
        Button[] btn = new Button[]{btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4};
        Random rn = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            int d = rn.nextInt(4) + 1;
            new Timeline(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), new KeyValue(btn[d - 1].opacityProperty(), .1)),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), new KeyValue(btn[d - 1].opacityProperty(), 1))
            ).play();
            //PAUSE HERE//
        }
    }
```

Comment: why you want to avoid Threads?

Comment: check my edit @Batmannn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the timeline's ability to loop and auto-reverse:

```
Timeline t = new Timeline(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), new KeyValue(btn[d - 1].opacityProperty(), .1)),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), new KeyValue(btn[d - 1].opacityProperty(), 1))
            );
t.setAutoReverse(true);
t.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE); 
t.play();
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible without thread, with a classic `Thread.sleep(500)` call.

But your whole UI thread will sleep, meaning other controls on your UI will not work during those 500ms.

---

**EDIT**

As said below the problem is that `Timeline.play()` is asynchronous. If you do not want to work with additional threads, create a synchronous code.

```
public void blink() {
    Button[] btn = new Button[]{btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4};
    Random rn = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int d = rn.nextInt(4) + 1;

        btn[d - 1].setOpacity(.1);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        btn[d - 1].setOpacity(1);
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Another solution, asynchronous with the `Timeline` but we only create one, big `Timeline`.

```
public void blink() {
    Button[] btn = new Button[]{btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4};
    Random rn = new Random();
    Timeline myTimeline = new Timeline();
    double millis = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int d = rn.nextInt(4) + 1;

        myTimeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(millis), new KeyValue(btn[d - 1].opacityProperty(), .1)));
        millis += 0.5;
        myTimeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(millis), new KeyValue(btn[d - 1].opacityProperty(), 1)));
        millis += 0.5;
    }

    myTimeline.play();
}
```

But that is one big `Timeline`.

Comment: And thats the problem that when UI thread sleeps, i can't see blinks. So I should use another thread for this task?

Comment: With a Timeline no, because it is an asynchronous operation (returns immediately after `play()`). I will edit my answer for a suggestion without the Timeline.