# How can I use sleep() in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

```
void bubbleSort() {
    for (int i = num - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if (ar[j] > ar[j+1]) {
                int t = ar[j];
                ar[j] = ar[j+1];
                ar[j+1] = t;
            }
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_SORT_MS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            draw();
        }
    }
}
```

I was making a program to visualize bubble sort using JavaFX, and `Thread.sleep()` did not work properly. Is it possible to make JavaFX wait for a moment?

Comment: Does this help? [Java, how to make a pause in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819975/java-how-to-make-a-pause-in-javafx)

Comment: Study and apply [Slaw’s guide to this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60685975/1155209).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this `Thread.sleep()` in this case.
Your program is only using one thread, and the graphic part is refreshing it selve 60 times per second (it dependes on you computer).

You can use `PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(0.3));`
or `Timeline timeline = new Timeline();`

Also you can see this links:

- https://www.codetd.com/es/article/14173904
- [How to properly execute Thread.sleep() in javaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881109/how-to-properly-execute-thread-sleep-in-javafx)

Comment: I challenge you to solve this with a PauseTransition or Timeline (i.e. provide working code for a BubbleSort animation).  I think you will find that tricky compared to a task that uses runLater.

Comment: @jewelsea [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62969241/2189127) an example for an insertion sort. Once you get your head around refactoring a sorting algorithm as a stateful object with a "do next step" method, it fits nicely into a `Timeline` :).

Comment: Yep, nice solution by James, you can use `Timeline` for this with some refactoring :-)